# Why is python getopt not parsing my options and instead think they are arguments?

Tags: python

I am attempting to use python's getopt to parse some input arguments, but my options are not recognised. Why does the following happen? What am I doing wrong?

```
>> $ ipython
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import getopt

In [2]: opts, args = getopt.getopt(['arg1', '-f', '-l'], "filo:t:", ["help", "output="])

In [3]: opts
Out[3]: []

In [4]: args
Out[4]: ['arg1', '-f', '-l']
```

Comment: Even if you have some reason to be using Python 2.7, you should perhaps be looking at `argparse` instead, as it's the forward-compatible alternative.

Comment: @tripleee, I'll look into it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[Python2.Docs]: getopt.getopt(args, options[, long_options])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt) (**emphasis** is mine):

> **Note**: Unlike GNU `getopt()`, **after a non-option argument, all further arguments are considered also non-options**. This is similar to the way non-GNU Unix systems work.

***arg1*** is such a non-option argument. Placing it at the end of the list (the 2<sup>nd</sup> call), would yield the expected output:

> ```py
> >>> import sys, getopt
> >>> sys.version
> '2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
> >>>
> >>> getopt.getopt(['arg1', '-f', '-l'], "filo:t:", ["help", "output="])
> ([], ['arg1', '-f', '-l'])
> >>>
> >>> getopt.getopt(['-f', '-l', 'arg1'], "filo:t:", ["help", "output="])
> ([('-f', ''), ('-l', '')], ['arg1'])
> ```

From the same page (what @tripleee also suggested):

> Note that an equivalent command line interface could be produced with less code and more informative help and error messages by using the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module: